Confluent schema registry 7.6.0 - issue with running multiple instances while publishing schemas
I have installed confluent schema registry based on “https://packages.confluent.io/archive/7.6/confluent-7.6.0.zip” on my on-premise
Kubernetes cluster,and pointing it to _schemas topic in Confluent Cloud Kafka.
When I run a single pod instance of schema registry (SR), I am able to publish new schemas to the SR consistently.
But when I run more than one pod instance, and the request hits the follower instance,the request fails with the error message like below,complaining about the follower instance unable to forward the request to leader due to "Unknown host" exception.
Error logs:

org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\nCaused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryRequestForwardingException: Unexpected error while forwarding the registering schema request to https://dp-schema-registry-7dc6cbdb5-kr2rk:1443\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.forwardRegisterRequestToLeader(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:1248)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.registerOrForward(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:880)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectVersionsResource.register(SubjectVersionsResource.java:412)\n\t… 73 more\nCaused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: dp-schema-registry-7dc6cbdb5-kr2rk

Basically the pods corresponding to the different SR instances in the same cluster are trying to reach each other using pod name and hence unable to resolve the target pod.If I manually try to connect to one pod from the other using the pod IP,they are able to connect.
My question is how do I let the pods interact with each other using pod Ip instead of pod name? I tried setting SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME to status.podIP in env variable section of pod,and it is able to set the variable to pod IP,but looks like the SR I is unable to understand this property and assign it to the pod host names.
Below are some of my settings in the schema registry properties:
listeners–> I have set it to “https://0.0.0.0:1443”
host.name → I have not set this
How do I let me follower pod connect/forward to leader pod of SR in above scenario?

You're running a pod manually? Could you use Confluent for Kubernetes to deploy a SchemaRegistry CRD and set replicas to more than one?

@OneCricketeer I am running schema registry pods on an onpremise K8 cluster as Deployment, using confluent provided docker image. Switching to alternates such as schemaregistry CRD or helm charts may help to resolve my issues, but at this moment we are not in a position to change the solution drastically. May be we will explore CRD in future. Would appreciate if you can guide me to some link on the CRD way of schema registry setup.  Regarding my issue, I managed to resolve ut by using initContainer to dynamically assign pod IP to host.name property in schemaregistry.properties.

You shouldn't need to use an init container. The env var for the pod ip should have worked. That's what the Confluent Helm Charts (now deprecated) had done. https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-schema-registry/templates/deployment.yaml#L78

Earlier I had tried assigning status.podIP to SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME which was successful, but the schema registry was not able to interpret that variable and assign to host.name internally, so pods were still communicating via pod names. Probably that could because the confluent schema registry zip I was using don't understand SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME variable.

Correct, the ZIP does not. The confluentinc/cp-schema-registry Docker image does, and you don't need the ZIP to run that.
